# Export filtered image (based on date) from Google Earth Engine for NDVI

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat-5

I am trying to export an NDVI image from Landsat5 to Drive but it seems like the date filter is not being applied in the exported image.

How do I resolve this?

Code below.

```
//Var geometry is a shapefile of area

var image = ee.Image(
  l8.filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate('2012-06-15', '2012-07-15')
);
 
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var ndvi = addNDVI(image).select('NDVI');

var withNDVI = l8.map(addNDVI);

var greenest = withNDVI.qualityMosaic('NDVI');

var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3};
Map.addLayer(greenest.clip(geometry), visParams, 'Greenest pixel composite');

var ndvi1 = greenest.select('NDVI').rename('ndvi');
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi1,
  description: 'ndvi2012',
  folder: 'Landsat5',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels: 1e9, 
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The image that you are exporting, `ndvi1`, is a quality mosaic of `l8`, which has not been filtered for your date range. You will notice this if you back-track your steps. Following your code, example of a solution:

```
//var withNDVI = l8.map(addNDVI); need to filter l8 by date
var withNDVI = l8.filterDate('2012-06-15', '2012-07-15').map(addNDVI)

var greenest = withNDVI.qualityMosaic('NDVI');

var ndvi1 = greenest.select('NDVI').rename('ndvi');

// proceed to export ndvi1
```

Note that I expect `l8.filterDate('2012-06-15', '2012-07-15')` to return an empty image collection because Landsat 5 was decommissioned in 2012 and the last available image is May 5 2012, according to the GEE data catalogue:  https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LT05_C01_T1_SR. I am assuming that `l8` is a collection of Landsat 5 images, as per your post, despite the misleading variable name.